# Simple random sampling - No natural strata

Tags: regression, logistic, survey

I have data from surveys given out to visitors to a branch of my organization. A random sampling of these visitors without regards to any strata was used to determine who gets the survey.

Given that surveys were randomly sent without any considering of a natural strata, can I

1. Use ordinary multivariate logistic regression to analyze the data or
2. Should I force a strata on the data using some discriminating condition (there really isn't any strong condition that could be used for stratification) and analyze the data using survey-weighted logistic regression?

I ask this question with the assumption that I cannot use methods for survey data analysis if my data used random sampling with no strata.

Comment: Have you looked at our threads on [post-stratification](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=post-stratification)?

Comment: @whuber I was able to post-stratify the data and used survey-weighted logistic regression in R to analyze the data. Since there are no model selection methods for survey data analysis (correct me if I am wrong), I simply implemented a stepwise reduction of aic in R since the svyglm objects in R have an associate AIC statistics for model fit. Do you see any obvious problem I may encounter during peer review based on the statistical approach for model selection?